# Is multiple php5-fpm processes normal

Tags: ubuntu, php, php-fpm

I'm running several wordpress sites in a LEMP (Ubuntu Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP) stack. Looking at the running processes I can see there are two php5-fpm processes.

Is this normal or have I done something? I'm more used to a LAMP stack and think I only usually had one php process running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's entirely normal. Each PHP-FPM process can only handle a single request at a time, so PHP-FPM fires up multiple (known as a pool) to handle more than one concurrent request.

A LAMP stack wouldn't have any PHP processes, as PHP executes within Apache using mod_php.

Comment: thanks. Although on Apache you can still run php seperately with fast cgi.